# Why is one of my reference properties not being included when using LINQ to Entities Include()?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have the following property declarations and mappings (abridged classes):

```
public class Consumer: AuditableEntity
{
    public virtual Consumer Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Consumer> Consumers { get; set; }
}

public ConsumerMap()
{
    HasRequired(t => t.Role)
        .WithMany(t => t.Consumers)
        .Map(a => a.MapKey("RoleId"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    HasRequired(t => t.User)
        .WithOptional(t => t.Consumer)
        .Map(a => a.MapKey("UserId"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

A manual database query confirms all joins are successful and in fact, a manual execution of the query sent by EF is successful. Yet when I use the following query, the `User` property on the two `Consumer` objects returned is null:

```
return CurrentDbContext.Consumers.Include("User").Include("Role").Where(e => !e.IsDeleted);
```

Comment: How do you execute the query in the last code snippet? By directly applying `ToList()` or do you add a `Select` or something in between?

Comment: @Slauma I 'append' another `Where` to the funtion call that invokes the last snippet, i.e. `ListAll().Where(blah).ToList()`

Comment: The second mapping doesn't look correct. It's a one-to-one mapping but you are mapping the key apparently to a foreign key "UserId" which is probably not the primary key in `Consumer`, or is it? Would be a strange name though. Foreign key one-to-one associations are not supported in EF.

Comment: Any resolution on this??  I am having the same problem.